# Widget not changing on Tap in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

So I am trying to build an Instagram like image editor with all the functionality. I wanted to switch between a text field and a simple Text Widget on tapping on either of them. I found an example online but it does not work in my case.

```
class _StateTextFieldState extends State<StateTextField> {
  FocusNode focusNode;
  GlobalKey key = GlobalKey();
  TextEditingController controller;
  Offset offset = Offset(1, 1);
  Color textColor;
  double fontSize;
  bool highlighted;
  final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
  Color pickerColor = Color(0xffffffff);
  Color currentColor = Color(0xffffffff);

  void changeColor(Color color) {
    setState(() => pickerColor = color);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    highlighted = widget.highlighted;
    focusNode = widget.focusNode;
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        highlighted = true;
      });
    });
    controller = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double fontSize = 24;
    String text = "Enter Text!";
    bool isEditing = false;
    double textWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6;
    return Container(
      key: key,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
      child: MatrixGestureDetector(
          onMatrixUpdate: (Matrix4 m, Matrix4 tm, Matrix4 sm, Matrix4 rm) {
            setState(() {
              notifier.value = m;
            });
          },
          child: Transform(
            transform: notifier.value,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    border: highlighted
                        ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2)
                        : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),

                  // color: Colors.redAccent,
                  width: textWidth,
                  child:
                      //_editTitleTextField(controller)
                      isEditing
                          ? TextField(
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              autofocus: true,
                              onEditingComplete: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  text = controller.text;
                                  isEditing = false;
                                  focusNode.unfocus();
                                  print(isEditing);
                                  highlighted = false;
                                });
                              },
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: currentColor, fontSize: fontSize),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                  ),
                                  fillColor: Colors.red,
                                  hintText: "Enter text",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                              maxLines: 1,
                              focusNode: focusNode,
                              //  maxLength: 100,
                            )
                          : Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  text,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                ),
                                IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.white),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        print(widget);
                                        isEditing = true;
                                        print(isEditing);
                                      });
                                    })
                              ],
                            ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
          //         ),
          ),
    );
  }
```

My problem is that even though isEditing changes on clicking the Iconbutton, the widget does not rebuild and remains the same. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to move your variables from build method to class method. Currently each time you rebuild your widget ( for example by taping on a button ) your variables will be get default values

```
class _StateTextFieldState extends State<StateTextField> {
 ... your code...
 double fontSize = 24;
 String text = "Enter Text!";
 bool isEditing = false;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ... your code ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been building Flutter Apps for more than a year, but still couldn't debug it. Such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that , you are using setState and functionality of setState is to rebuild the UI again by calling the build function.

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   double fontSize = 24;
   String text = "Enter Text!";
   bool isEditing = false;

   return Container(
   .. . .. 
   . . . 
}
```

So whenever you call setState ,each time this function is called and your variables are getting re-initialized , hence ,you need to make these variables as class members, instead of making them local variable of build function.

```
class _StateTextFieldState extends State<StateTextField> {
bool isEditing =false;
. . . 
. . .
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container( . . );
}
```

Hope this helps!